# "Take a flying leap": is that down or off something, to your death?

Tags: expressions, idioms

The question is about telling someone to go *take a flying [leap](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/flying%20leap)* (BrE *flying jump*) for "tell[ing] someone who angers or annoys you to go away." (*Merriam Learners*). It seems the noun [*flyer*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flyer) is semantically related with a possible meaning [based](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=flyer&allowed_in_frame=0) on the notion of flying jump/leap, as with "*he took a flier off the bridge*" (*Dictionary.com*).

---

- Is there any ellipsis of some complement using the preposition
  *down/off* when you say "go take a flying leap" i.e. *down* to hell/the drain, *off* the bridge/cliff?. Or is it just the leap
  meaning *far away+fast*?
- Is that going away or is there any connotation about going *to
  die/[suicide](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/29785)*?
- How is it different from the dismissive *go curl into a ball an die*?
  Is it more expressive than telling someone to *get [lost](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/lost%5B2%5D)*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Take a flying leap** *(off a bridge)*

is a colloquialism telling someone **to go away** or **get lost** and hopefully **never come back**

Other ways of expressing the same message are

> **go curl up in a ball and die**
>   **take a long walk off a short pier**
>   **Got a dime? Go tell someone who cares!** *(when payphones were more prevalent)*

Comment: Thank you. You add _off a bridge_ in parens: are you implying the idiom includes "off a bridge" i.e. the ellipsis I'm talking about? I understand many expressions communicate the same message but are they all exactly equal? Is it "never come back" because you're dead?

Comment: The parenthesis are to show that something can be added: off a bridge, off a cliff, etc. They are all equal in terms of saying "go away".